# Url appending 2nd querystring when using @Html.PagedListPager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, I have a search box and when I enter a search phrase and submit the form the url is:

```
http://localhost:50435/Search-Results-For?q=hotels&Option=Web&Page=1
```

When the results are returned, I can then page and the url is:

```
http://localhost:50435/Search-Results-For/hotels/web/2
```

But if I then try to do another search, that search is appended to the url above:

```
http://localhost:50435/Search-Results-For/hotels/web/2?q=poole&Option=web&Page=2
```

I have no idea how to solve this, I have tried putting the pager in a partialview, changing the parameters but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone had this problem before or knows how to solve it.

Pager:

```
<div id="dvPagePager">@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.SearchResults, page => Url.Action("Results", new { Page = page, q = @ViewBag.q, Option = @ViewBag.b}), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)</div>
```

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("SearchEngine", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "frmSearchEngine" }))
                                    {
                                   { Html.RenderAction("pvSearchForm", "Home"); }
                                   //Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/pvSearchForm.cshtml");
                                    }
```

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SearchEngine",
                url: "Search-Results-For/{q}/{Option}/{Page}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Results", q = UrlParameter.Optional, Option = UrlParameter.Optional, Page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by making the form a standard html form, the added a URL.Action with http, this forced the url to refresh when doing a new post